# Best practices for clear field control in field with right-justified text?

Tags: input-fields

A form we've created has $ amounts right justified. What's best practice for including a "clear field" control within the field?

Current thinking is that the hover state pushes the $ amount to the left, revealing an "X" control.

Another option is to put the "X" on the left, which would have the benefit of not making the $ amount jump left every time you hover.

Thoughts?

Comment: Not a solution, but an anecdote: I know of one program (Clementine music player) that uses a left-aligned "clear field" function, and I always feel the field (rather, the icon) looks strange. It took me a while until I tried it.

Comment: That's our thinking as well. It would seem strange.

Comment: May you share the screen of your application?